# JIC Image compression Technique not working for PNG Images

Tags: javascript

JIC Compression works only for JPG Images but if i upload PNG File compression will not work my code is as below:

```
var jic = {

     * @param {Image} source_img_obj The source Image Object
     * @param {Integer} quality The output quality of Image Object
     * @param {String} output format. Possible values are jpg and png
     * @return {Image} result_image_obj The compressed Image Object
     */

    compress: function(source_img_obj, quality, output_format){

         var mime_type = "image/jpeg";//mime_type can be png as well.

         var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
         cvs.width = source_img_obj.naturalWidth;
         cvs.height = source_img_obj.naturalHeight;
         var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);
         var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality/100);
         alert(newImageData);
         var result_image_obj = new Image();
         result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
         return result_image_obj;
    },
```

Comment: see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-canvas-element  Quality parameter at toDataURL method affects only on jpeg (or webp).

Comment: or is there any way to compress data in Javascript or jquery. so that i can pass compressed data from browser to server. And in server side i can handle the compression .Thank you for your reply

Comment: Crient side PNG image compression is not so easy since you should create optimized PNG binary by using imagebitmap of canvas, like this https://github.com/imaya/CanvasTool.PngEncoder (written in japanese...)

Comment: okay thank you sir